# the_content inside my own theme does not retain line breaks / enters like in the admin

Tags: the-content, formatting

Ok, I tried everything. the_content, get_the_content, filters, disabling plugins, Chtulu. Nothing.

In my own theme, the content retains the format given in the admin editor (like bold, italic, justify...) but not line breaks.

The text is "all together", all "attached". I can't "detach" subtitles from the paragraph, for example.

What should I look for?

Answer (score 0):

Check if any of these you have in your theme's functions.php file.

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wptexturize' );
```

remove those.